# Python selenium webdriver: list index out of range maximum 5 elements

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling, webdriver

Hello I am using selenium  on twitter to click on multiple reply button with `driver.find_elements_by_xpath`
The problem I am facing is that I can only click on 5 elements not more. here is the print of the list

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cc78e4de72bea5cfc9499af03f3e9271", 
element="c9beaf38-e9a9-46af-baa8-eff476c87be8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="cc78e4de72bea5cfc9499af03f3e9271", element="7cd7649f-efc5-48b5-9e68-3d97a96e72cc")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cc78e4de72bea5cfc9499af03f3e9271", 
element="6d1e9ce9-9b17-4f69-8c49-0805331549fd")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement 
(session="cc78e4de72bea5cfc9499af03f3e9271", element="1c4f540d-2dfe-4ed5-80ba-01bf5ba1a389")>, 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="cc78e4de72bea5cfc9499af03f3e9271", 
element="0eaa0f99-0e62-45cf-bc57-fef86ac30e03")>]
```

You can clearly count 5 elements

And here is my code

```
reply1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="reply"]/div/div[1]')
count = 0
reply1[count].click()
                
                
count = count + 1
print (count)
print(reply1)
sleep(4)
driver.back()


except common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:
   time.sleep(2)                                                                          
   driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")                             
   time.sleep(2)
```

and I am getting this error:

```
reply1[count].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
PS C:\Users\92\Desktop\new features test\new feature> 
[7300:18956:0320/013757.708:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(924)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL 
error code 1, net_error -101
```

UPDATE: I did some changes and the code is working on 9 elements,

```
count = 0 

running = True
while running:
 
            

    loop = True
    while loop:

    reply1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="reply"]/div/div[1]')
    
    reply = reply1[count] 

    sleep(1)
    
    
    print(reply)
    reply1[count].click()

    #comment_buttons[count].click()

    
    sleep(4)


    driver.back()
    loop = False
    

count = count + 1
print (count)

           
sleep(1) 
time.sleep(2)  
                                                                     
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
                                               
print ("d2")                        
time.sleep(2)
```

After opening 9 elements I am gettings this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\92\Desktop\new features test\new feature\test copy.py", line 
155, in <module>
reply = reply1[count]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: If it only finds 5 then either trying scrolling down if it has lazy load or wait for all elements to be present.

Comment: I did scroll and wait for more than 30 second it's not working, but instead it's skip 5 elements and work on the next 5

Answer (score 0):

As [@Arundeep Chohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan) mentioned in his comment, Twitter has this feature called "lazy load", where you have to manually scroll down to see the next tweets.

In your code, it looks like you are trying to scroll, using

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
```

but this code is placed inside an "except" clause. I am not sure if it ever gets executed, because that error (*ElementClickInterceptedException*) probably does not happen. You only have 5 elements and all of them can be clicked, no clicks are intercepted.

However, you increased your counter before, without knowing if reply1 contains a 6th tweet (which it seems it doesn't).

So, I suggest you place your "scrolling" code outside the exception. Use a loop to scroll how many times you want at the beginning, store the elements you find each time in a list and finally, iterate that list and click the reply button in each element.

UPDATE: I think your new code is a bit more confusing than before, but you are getting close. I will try to explain it with some pseudo-code:

```
for _ in range(3):         # loop as many times as you want to scroll
    tweets = find elements 
    for tweet in tweets:
        click_reply_button
        sleep
    scroll_window
    sleep
```

Comment: how can I store elements in a list ?

Comment: I have done somethings but it's very strange now, it working fine with the first 5 elements, then it's skip the next 5 elements, and work on the 5 next, Check my Update

Comment: I think the problem is with the order you do each step: first, you collect your 5 elements, then you iterate through each of them, you click the button for each element and at the same time you try to scroll. It would probably be better to: (1) collect 5 elements, like you did, (2) loop through each one of them and click it, (3) out of the loop, scroll the window. Then, use an outer loop and repeat the whole process, from 1 to 3. You will probably have some duplicates each time you scroll, because the previous tweets will be collected again.

Comment: how should I loop through each one of them and click it, I did some correction I have edit the code above and it's working on 9 elements now, it's strange

Comment: I have try , but ElementClickInterceptedException came, I also try to to handle it by scrolling, but it's scrolling non stop `for _ in range(6):        scroll
    tweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="reply"]/div/div[1]')
    for tweet in tweets:
    
        tweet.click()
        sleep(2)
        driver.back()
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 200)")
    sleep(3)`